# Are Sencha Touch 2.3.1 apps supported on Black Berry default browser?

Tags: html, blackberry, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've built a Sencha Touch (2.3.1) app and run sencha app build production, deployed it to OpenShift (JBoss, not that it matters but I like the service :P) and I can access it from Android's default browser,chrome, but I just saw that it never loads on BB :(, but I was told that BB had a pretty good support for HTML5 so ...

Does BB default browser renders ST apps ?

Do I have to do something special to enable rendering on that browser ?

[Here is the demo app](http://prosp-anonym111.rhcloud.com/simulador/build/production/reestructura/index.html)

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a Blackberry 10 device? BB10 is supported by Sencha Touch, so if you're having problems with that platform I would recommend asking on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum).

Comment: Is ST only supported on that platform?

Comment: Ok, and do I have to something special to add support?